# Linq GroupBy filter

Tags: linq, group-by

I have the following linq expression pulling all data from my database:

```
var items = response.Select(a => a.SessionLocationID).ToArray();
mdl = _meetingRepository.Select<SessionLocation>()
    .OrderBy(a => a.SessionDT).ThenBy(a => a.SessionEndTime);
```

Now I want to group by the field ActualRoom and only the ones with ActualRoom count > 3

Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`, just keep in mind that you are losing the ordering you already did so I would start off before you do the sorting:

```
var groups =  _meetingRepository.Select<SessionLocation>()
                                .GroupBy(x => x.ActualRoom)
                                .Where(g => g.Count() > 3)
```

To have *sorted* groups - assuming preserving the count as a separate property is not neccessary you can just project to an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable<SessionLocation>`:

```
var groups =  _meetingRepository.Select<SessionLocation>()
                                .GroupBy(x => x.ActualRoom)
                                .Where(g => g.Count() > 3)
                                .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.SessionDT).ThenBy(x => x.SessionEndTime));
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I totally understand loosing the ordering, but is it possible to have the results sorted in the dictionary?

Comment: you want the items *within* each group sorted?

Comment: yes. I want the items within each group sorted at least by SessionDT and if it is possible by SessionEndTime too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to have sorted groups and and preserve the count?

Comment: yes you can project to either an anonymous class or a dedicated class with both the count and the enumeration (even though its very easy to reconstruct the count manually..)